# Int, bool values not getting set in web service asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, soapui

I am calling a web service in asp.net made in php. While calling php service from SOAP UI or any third party tool all objects in that service is getting set except those who are in int, bool.

Objects with data type string is getting passed from asp.net and reaching in php.

Comment: you should try json instead of soap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same issue earlier. Can you check if your data contract have any field for integers. If property name is Length then there must be a property named LengthSpecified. Just set it to true.